# Installing Navicat on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, wine, navicat

is there a way to install Navicat on Ubuntu 14.04 without using wine? just straight up from deb or apt-get install.. I tried installing it using wine, but the problem is it does not function well enough. thanks

Answer (score 31):

New Version of Navicat:

Download:
https://navicat.com/download/direct-download?product=navicat15-mysql-en.AppImage&location=1

Open terminal

Go to Downloads folder:
`cd Downloads/`

Give power to run:
`chmod +x navicat15-mysql-en.AppImage`

open Navicat:
`./navicat15-mysql-en.AppImage`

source: https://navicat.com/en/download/navicat-for-mysql#lin

Comment: The link seems to be dead: "The specified key does not exist"

Comment: The answer was from 2015. Now you can download from: https://navicat.com/download/direct-download?product=navicat15-mysql-en.AppImage&location=1 
I will update the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may also want to add a shortcut to the applications menu. Got it from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748626/create-launcher-icon-for-navicat) post

Create a new entry in     `/usr/share/applications`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Navicat
Comment=Database Admin Tool
Exec=/bin/sh  "/opt/navicat/start_navicat"
Icon=/path/to/icon
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Wine;
StartupNotify=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find resource to intall linux version on: http://www.navicat.com/download/navicat-for-mysql